# Using cursor in procedure

Tags: plsql

Why am I getting the error below and please tell me what's wrong in the code.
ORA-06511: PL/SQL: cursor already open

Code :

```
create or replace procedure student_info IS  
c_id student_details.student_id%type  ;      
c_name student_details.student_name%type;  
c_status student_details.student_status%type;

cursor stu_c1 IS  
select *  from student_details  
where student_status='Absent';  
begin  
open stu_c1;  
Fetch stu_c1 into c_id,c_name,c_status ;  
for rec in stu_c1 loop  
insert into student_data values (c_status,c_id,c_name);  
commit;  
end loop;   
CLOSE stu_c1;    
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `FOR` loop with explicit cursor, you don't need `open/fetch/close/handle NOTFOUND`.

```
...
begin  
--open stu_c1;   -- extra, not needed
--Fetch stu_c1 into c_id,c_name,c_status ;   -- extra, not needed
for rec in stu_c1 loop    -- that's enough
insert into student_data values (c_status,c_id,c_name);  
....
end loop;   
--CLOSE stu_c1;  -- not needed
```

Alternatively, you do open, fetch, close, handle `NOTFOUND`, but not use `FOR ... IN`.

Comment: Thanks, but the data is not getting inserted into the  "student_data" table because we are not assigning any values to c_status,c-

Comment: Didn't you forget commit?    Also, check syntax. With `FOR` loop you need to insert like `insert into student_data values (rec.student_status ,rec.id,rec.name);  ` assuming student_status , id, and name are fields in `student_details ` table